# Show element mouse hover only css

Tags: css

This example work perfect:

```css
true
html {
  background-color: beige;
}

.at2 {
  display: none;
}

.at:hover+.at2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="at">test 1</a>

<a class="at2">TEST 2</a>
```

But, this example doesn't work:

```css
html {
  background-color: beige;
}

.at2 {
  display: none;
}

.divtype1 .at:hover+.divtype2 .at2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="divtype1">
  <a class="at">test 1</a>
</div>

<div class="divtype2">
  <a class="at2">TEST 2</a>
</div>
```

I'm learning CSS, can someone tell me how to make it work in the second example?
(In the first example it works, quite simple, but in reality it is never like that).

Thank you.

Comment: Please make it as easy as possible for us to help you, by including all relevant code here, preferably as a [MCVE]. Don't make us go offsite to find vital info.

Comment: Add your code in tihs question itself instead of external link. Understand the functionality `+` in CSS. It is the next immediate child. As per your example, `.divtype1 .at:hover + .divtype2 .at2`. divtype2 is not immediate child of `.at`. If you wrtie your code `.divtype1:hover + .divtype2 .at2` then it will work in the second example

Comment: CSS is parsed sequentially, from ancestor to descendant and sibling to next sibling. It can not traverse up to parents or to previous siblings. For that you need javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting `.divtype1 .at:hover + .divtype2 .at2`, but your problem is that the `+` selector looks for an element directly after it. In this case, it is looking for a `.divtype2 .at2` right next to the `.at:hover`, but there isn't one.

```css
.at2 {
  display: none;
}
.at:hover + .at2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- This works because `.at2` comes directly after `.at`-->
<a class="at">at</a>
<a class="at2">at2</a>
```